# Shell object moving weirdly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My "Shell" object **when i spawn it, moves forward but then moves backward and does a full circle**. Here is the code i put on the Shell(its 2 different scripts). if you see what the problem is, thank you.  Using **2019 Unity** btw lol =')

**SCRIPT 1**

```
public List<GameObject> powerupList;
public int randomNumberInList;
public GameObject chosenPowerup;
public float spawnDistance = 3f;
bool canSpawnPowerup = true;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && chosenPowerup && canSpawnPowerup)
    {
        Vector3 spawnPos = transform.position + transform.forward * spawnDistance;
        Instantiate(chosenPowerup, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity, null);
        canSpawnPowerup = false;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "itemBoxes")
    {
        randomNumberInList = Random.Range(0, powerupList.Count);
        chosenPowerup = powerupList[randomNumberInList];
    }
}
```

**SCRIPT 2**

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * 20;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("obstacle"))
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like nothing is giving velocity to your shell and for me the 1st script should be on your kart(I don't know, I assume you were making a mario kart like)

Comment: what's keeping your shell pointing in the right direction? if it spins off course then itl just keep going in the wrong direction. Also btw, including the names of your scripts can help give us context to your code :)